# Is there an alternative to the taps gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

Looking for an alternative to the 'taps' gem, which hasn't been developed in 10 months. It requires SQLite, which Heroku's Cedar stack doesn't support, so I'm trying to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option that Heroku suggests is PG Backups. It supports backing up to and restoring from a local environment, which is essentially what Taps does. You can see their documentation on it here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups